# Getting the length of a String Token

Tags: c, token, strtok, strlen

C Programming:

I'm attempting to get the length of each word inside a string, but having massive troubles and get a segmentation fault no matter what method I use.

I was originally trying to use just "strlen(pstr)" but that caused segmentation fault.

This is my latest attempt which still causes segmentation fault:

```
void format_text(char* text)
{
    char* pstr;
    char  copied[1000];
    int   loop;
    int   strCnt = 0;
    int   temp;
    int   strSize[100];
    int   strNo[100];

    pstr = strtok(text, " ");
    while (pstr != NULL)
    {
        pstr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcpy(copied, pstr);
        strSize[strCnt] = strlen(copied);
        strCnt++;
    }

    printf("the number of strings is: %d\n", strCnt);
    for (loop = 0; loop < strCnt; loop++)
    {
        printf("The length of string %d is %d\n", loop + 1, strSize[loop]);
    }
}
```

How can I get and print the length of each word(token)?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be calling `format_text` on a read-only string literal, would you?

Comment: I'm not 100% what a string literal is as I'm only a beginner in C, but I would assume not. It is just user input of a normal string with fgets. 

I am able to print out the pointer (pstr) but have no way of using strlen on it. strlen is supposed to work fine on pointers, but I get a segmentation fault from it in this instance. No idea why.

I assumed to copy pstr into a string and strlen that, but i get a segmentation fault from that too.

Comment: For example `"this is a string literal"`.  So just some hard-coded text between `""`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `copied` string to get the lenght, you can simply use `pstr`.  And, you need to put the `strtok()` after the `strlen()`, otherwise you'll miss the length of the first word.

Here's what should work:

```
    pstr = strtok(text, " ");
    while (pstr != NULL)
    {
        strSize[strCnt++] = strlen(pstr);

        pstr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok()` function returns `pstr == NULL` when there are no further tokens to return, however your code does not take notice of this and instead immediately calls `strcpy(copied, pstr);`, which will result in your crash. Check for NULL and terminate the loop immediately before otherwise using pstr.

For bonus learning points, walk through this in your debugger to follow exactly what happens.